# How to say "What am I going to do with you" in Chinese?

Tags: word-requests

There is an expression in English of sort of dramatic frustration, but in a very familiar, and almost endearing way.  So, for example, if your girlfriend/boyfriend does something that is kind of unique or strange, but it is very specific to them, you can exclaim, "What am I going to do with you!"

It is hard for me to explain this expression, and I cannot find a good webpage for it.  But I am looking for a way in Chinese to sort of "mock complain" about something slightly weird that someone you care about does.  Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a Chinese expression that almost perfectly matches the English one:

**我该拿你怎么办**

And it is used endearingly, or critically by superiors on inferiors. This also seems to match the English usage.

I don't know about its etymology; from its close match against English and its contemporaneity (Ngram Viewer shows it [appeared in the 80's and began to spike from the 90's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%E6%8B%BF%E4%BD%A0%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E5%8A%9E&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=23&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%E6%8B%BF%20%E4%BD%A0%20%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%20%E5%8A%9E%3B%2Cc0)) I suspect it is highly influenced by the English expression.

Comment: I think 拿你没办法 is more *accurate*

Comment: @user3306356 这样太直白，没有体现当事人的迷茫，无助和绝望

Answer (score 1):

Another even more idiomatic way to say this is:

- 拿你没辙 ná nǐ méi zhé

It's used basically just as 拿你怎么办, in an endearing, familiar way. The character [辙 zhé](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%BE%99) has the meaning of 办法, so the idiom literally means "no way to take you", and is used just as your description.